# Pass args in an arrow function to a control

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a child component with a method that has an argument.  I can call that method just fine with using a integer as the argument, or a parameter.  But not as a string value inside of quotes directly.

Below is my code that does work...

```
<SampleAlertButton @ref=alertSystem></SampleAlertButton>

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="() => alertSystem.AlertSuccess(message)">Show Successful Alert 2.0</button>

@code{
    private SampleAlertButton alertSystem;

    private string message="Success Message from Code!";
}
```

Below is what I would like to be able to do, but can't, I get an error saying closing parentheses are missing.

```
<SampleAlertButton @ref=alertSystem></SampleAlertButton>

<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="() => alertSystem.AlertSuccess("My Inline Message")">Show Successful Alert 2.0</button>

@code{
    private SampleAlertButton alertSystem;
}
```

Why does the last one not work, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `@` symbol to switch to C# and a set of parenthesis around the lambda expression:

`"@(() => alertSystem.AlertSuccess("My Inline Message"))"`

Comment: THANKS!!!  That did it!

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax to fix the issue you are facing

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=@(() => alertSystem.AlertSuccess("My Inline Message"))>Show Successful Alert 2.0</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

<button class="btn btn-success" **@onclick="@(() => alertSystem.AlertSuccess("My Inline Message"))**">Show Successful Alert 2.0